# Google GeoChart works on one domain and does not on another

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I know this is a vague question but than again this is a vague problem.

I have a simple Google GeoChart like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>


   <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['geochart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);

    var options = {'displayMode': 'markers'};

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

you can find it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/0rd3hp7a/

now here's the thing. I have 2 domains / url's linked to this .php file.

the map generates fine on one domain and on the other the map pops up but the green markers do not.

Both domains run under php 5.2.17 and the provider tells me that both domains have same settings ... which is hard to believe since they work differently of the SAME file.

Any ideas where I can look for the problem???

Comment: found one recent issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38346452/5090771), using the [alpha-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) vs. the text name resolved the issue

Comment: Hi @WhiteHat it's not the text I don't think. I actually have my data in my production files in a JSON table. In the example above the data is in text. I used current and older google-vis versions. Tried all combinations I could think of... the 2 domains use the SAME ONE .php file.... yet the geochart works on one and does not on the other. Not really looking for an answer but for a clue where to look for that answer. Thank you anyway for your effort.

Comment: no errors show in the browser console?